# Connecting flight checked bag

Tags: customs-and-immigration, luggage, eu, connecting-flights

I will be leaving from the US going to Germany and then to Spain.

Will I have to re-check my bag before going on my connecting flight because I know when you go into the US you have to reclaim your bag and then re-check it in.

> I believe it’s a **single ticket**.
> I’m flying United airlines to **Frankfurt** then to **Barcelona** my only issue is, I only have an hour and a half layover

Comment: Are the flight under a single ticket? If yes, the answer below is correct. Else you probably have to recheck.

Comment: I believe it’s a single ticket. I’m flying United airlines to Frankfurt then to Barcelona my only issue is, I only have an hour and a half layover

Answer (score 2):

Barcelona is a main international airport, your luggage will be checked through.

Of course you should check that it is labeled right when you hand it in.

Your short layover is not exceptionally short, so unless your incoming plane is delayed you should make it and see your luggage in Barcelona. There you will pass through the channels, red, green and possibly blue. You should take the green if nothing to declare or the red one when you have things to declare. Your luggage tag will show you started outside the EU and customs officers can easily see that. Blue, if there, is for people who travel within the European Union, so not you.

Comment: The blue or green channel may only be used if you have nothing to declare to Customs.

Comment: In my answer is written that you need the green for nothing to declare and the red when you have things to declare. The blue is for within the EU and you should not have to declare items when you travel within the EU, and OP should not use that channel anyhow.

Comment: Even within the EU there are certain limits (and sometimes items that are restricted) that then must be declared. Also cash above €10000. For this the red channel must be used. Where, other than Ireland, have you seen a blue channel?

Comment: [Customs & Immigration Process | Dublin Airport](https://www.dublinairport.com/at-the-airport/security/customs-immigration): **EU arrivals** If your journey was entirely within the EU, use the blue channel after reclaiming your baggage. Customs officers will monitor this area and may operate checks. **If you have something to declare to Customs, you should go to the red point**.

Comment: There used to be blue channels at some UK airports as well, but I do indeed not remember having seen them anywhere else. Coming from Switzerland I always need to take the green channel anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Since the customs comes under the control of each member country, you have to go through customs only at final airport. A very rare exception is if the final airport is small enough not to have any customs facility (domestic only), you may have to recheck bags.

You will go through the immigration at Germany (first point of entry in Schengen area) anyway. In any case, confirm with your airline when checking in for the flight.

Comment: Do you have an example for such an exception? I've flown to Europe dozens (if not 100s)  of times and never had to do this. I don't even know how this would work: European airports have no "re-check" area like the US does. Would you have to lug it all the way to the check in counter and re-check the bag ?

Comment: @Hilmar That's a very rare case. For Germany, see here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airports_in_Germany Scroll to bottom. There are domestic only airports. You are landing on one of those airports on connection is unlikely.

Comment: The bottom of the page has a list of closed airports.  The main list is alphabetical.  Which airports are you talking about?

Comment: @Hilmar When connecting from an international flight to a domestic one ("domestic" in the ordinary sense, not "Schengen") at certain airports in Scandinavia, you have to go through customs at the connecting hub, though both [Oslo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TGukTF8Aelg) and [Helsinki](https://www.finavia.fi/en/airport/customs?navref=main) have programs so that this can, in most circumstances, be done without physically retrieving your bags.

Comment: Mark explained it well in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your final destination is **not** contained in the [List of international Union airports](https://taxation-customs.ec.europa.eu/document/download/a34f065b-334e-49df-ad8a-e263ae4d2cb6_en?filename=List%20of%20International%20Union%20Airports%20%283%29.pdf) PDF for Spain, then it is likely your **registered baggage** will be checked at the first EU airport.

Based on the list for Germany, many regional (i.e. domestic) airports have the facilities for customs controls that can be carried out on registered baggage.

Since Barcelona is listed, your baggage will be transfered to that flight when you have a single ticket.

In Frankfurt you will go through Immigration and customs controls. Should your registered baggage contain anything that needs to be declared, that declaration should be done in Frankfurt (where you are entering the customs area).

---

> [Taxation and Customs Union - Travelling by air](https://taxation-customs.ec.europa.eu/customs-4/customs-controls/travelling-air_en)
> **How do these controls operate in practice ?**
> That depends on your situation:
> ...
> 5. **Are you taking a flight between a non-EU airport and an EU airport with a change of plane in another EU airport? (e.g. Tokyo - Copenhagen - Amsterdam with a change of aircraft in Copenhagen)**
> You will get off the first plane in Copenhagen where your **hand baggage** is liable to be checked by customs. Meanwhile, your registered baggage, which will have been given a normal label (no green edges) in Tokyo, will be transferred from the baggage hold of the first plane to that of the second).
> On arrival in Amsterdam , your hand baggage will not, in theory, be liable to be checked by customs, whereas your registered baggage may be.
> **If the second EU airport is not equipped for air traffic with third countries (See, for information, the *list of international Union airports*), your registered baggage will be liable to be checked in the first EU airport**.

From: [list of international Union airports](https://taxation-customs.ec.europa.eu/document/download/a34f065b-334e-49df-ad8a-e263ae4d2cb6_en?filename=List%20of%20International%20Union%20Airports%20%283%29.pdf) PDF in Germany (some of which no longer exist):

- Flughafen Augsburg
- Flughafen Berlin-Schönefeld
- Flughafen Berlin-Tegel (closed)
- Zentralflughafen Berlin-Tempelhof (closed)
- Flughafen Bremen
- Flughafen Cochstedt
- Flughafen Dortmund
- Flughafen Dresden
- Flughafen Düsseldorf
- Landeplatz Egelsbach (Hessen)
- Flughafen Erfurt
- Flughafen Frankfurt Main
- Flugplatz Friedrichshafen
- Flughafen Hamburg
- Flughafen Hannover
- Flughafen Karlsruhe/Baden-Baden
- Flughafen Köln/Bonn
- Flughafen Leipzig/Halle
- Flughafen Mönchengladbach
- Flughafen München
- Flughafen Münster/Osnabrück
- Flughafen Nürnberg
- Flughafen Paderborn/Lippstadt
- Flughafen Rostock-Laage
- Flughafen Saarbrücken
- Flughafen Stuttgart

> [List of airports in Germany - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airports_in_Germany)
> [image]

The following airports in Germany (based on the Wikipedia image) are not contained in the list of Union airports:

- Barth, Braunschweig, Cuxhaven, Heringsdorf, Ingolstadt, Kassel, Magdeburg, Memmingen, Neubrandenburg, Niederrhein, Oberpfaffenhofen, Siegerland, Sylt and Zweibrücken

Should your final destination be one of these airports, then assume that your registered baggage will be checked at the first EU airport. You should ask your airline for details.

---

**Sources**:

- [Taxation and Customs Union - Travelling by air](https://taxation-customs.ec.europa.eu/customs-4/customs-controls/travelling-air_en)

  - [List of international Union airports](https://taxation-customs.ec.europa.eu/document/download/a34f065b-334e-49df-ad8a-e263ae4d2cb6_en?filename=List%20of%20International%20Union%20Airports%20%283%29.pdf) (PDF) dated 2022

  > This list comprises all Union airports which, having been so authorized by the competent authorities of the Member State concerned, are approved for air traffic with third countries and where, in particular, customs controls can be carried out on baggage.
- [List of airports in Germany - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airports_in_Germany)

Comment: Don’t know the layout in Frankfurt, but in many airports the airside non-Schengen-to-Schengen checks only involve passport control, no customs in sight. Any declarations would happen at the final airport (unless of course one is subject to spot checks at the connecting airport).

Comment: This answer is all over the place.  First you openly contradict yourself about where "registered baggage" needs to be declared (text says Frankfurt, quoted text implies Spain), then you proceed to talk about destination airports in Germany when the OP is going to Spain.

Comment: @Doc The quote states that it can be **checked**, which is different than being declared.

Comment: Your statement about declaring in FRA is still wrong.  And the highlighted section in your quote is not in any way relevant for the OPs question, nor is the list of airports in Germany.

Comment: @Doc If you go throught the green lane and **later**, during a check, dutiable goods are found then this is considered to be a customs/tax fraud. [Customs controls on arrival at the airport or port](https://www.revenue.ie/en/customs/individuals/info-travelling-duty-free/from-outside-eu/controls.aspx): ***Note**: Once you pass beyond the Customs Warning Notice, you are effectively making a customs declaration. **Failure to present dutiable goods to Customs is an offence***. If you have a source that **explicitly** states otherwise, kindly supply that source.

Comment: @MarkJohnson The very thing you've quoted in your answer contradicts your statement for checked baggage.  (And that's without even considering that the OP almost certainly won't pass through a red/green checkpoint until BCN).  Yes, if you have carry-on baggage that contains items to declare you need it do it at FRA.  Checked baggage declaration occurs in BCN.  That is exactly what the text you've quoted says. It's also exactly why there is no need to collect bags at FRA, and also why the colour-coded baggage tag concept exists.